# Is WWW reliable for downloading a large AssetBundle?

Tags: unity

I have a very large AssetBundle. More than 200MB.

Is `WWW` reasonable for downloading it from my server? I heard that you can't tell the timeout it has. I intend to use it for iOS and Android.

Since clearly the download will last more than 5 minutes for a lot of people, is it reliable or will it time out? Should I instead make my own application in my server to transfer the bundle's bytes using sockets?

Comment: What is WWW? Do you mean HTTP?

Comment: @Thebluefish `WWW` is a class for getting content from URLs. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html - you can use it to download AssetBundles.

Comment: You could split your assets in several bundles if the only problem is the timeout

Comment: I'd just like to point out that making a mobile game that requires 200+MB downloads is a sure-fire way to get most of your players to stop playing your game before they even start.

Comment: @bcrist: I'm confident that it does not matter as long as it's a good game. I have previously released an 800 MB game last year, and it is still in the top 30.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking your assets into smaller bundles holds many advantages and only 2 disadvantages.

The advantages are that if you update some of the assets, users only have to download a portion of the asset data instead of the entire bundle.(unless you roll a decent updater)
This also means if some of the assets don't download properly, you again don't have to re download all of the assets. Finally, if you time out, you again, don't have to re download all of the assets, only the ones you missed.

There are 2 main disadvantages I can think of with this method but they are small enough that they aren't unreasonable. Making many assets will increase the download time but your talking about seconds. The other disadvantage is that since you have multiple asset bundles, you need to keep track of which asset bundle has what content.

Answer (score 0):

I using this code for downloading some pictures in my apps you can use it with some changes i never had any problem with this code

```
string uri; //Source Path
string fileName; //Destination Path

HttpWebRequest request_ = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (uri);
HttpWebResponse response_ = (HttpWebResponse)request_.GetResponse ();

if ((response_.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
     response_.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
     response_.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
    response_.ContentType.StartsWith ("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    using (Stream inputStream = response_.GetResponseStream())
    using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        do {
            bytesRead = inputStream.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            outputStream.Write (buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead != 0);
    }
}
```